# Como puedo poner los input en la misma fila con bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente formulario hecho con bootstrap y no me esta poniendo la fecha de inicio y hora de fin en la misma fila.
Aquí muestro una imagen como se mira, trato de poner los col-md-6 y no me los esta tomando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta parte tengo explicado como quisiera que se viera mi formulario, es decir que la Fecha de inicio y la Hora de inicio quede en la misma fila, lo mismo para la Fecha de fin y la hora de fin, **ASI QUIERO QUE SE VEA:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta parte comparto el código donde se encontrara un botón de Abrir Modal y se podrá ver el formulario:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Calendario WEB</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#form-events">
            Abrir Modal
        </button>
        <!-- Formulario de Eventos -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="form-events" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header" style="background:#293145;">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <input type="hidden" id="Id">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-12">
                                <label>Titulo del Evento:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="title-event" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label>Fecha de inicio:</label>
                                <div class="input-group" data-autoclose="true">
                                    <input type="date" id="start-date" class="form-control" value="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="title-hour-start">
                                <label>Hora de inicio:</label>
                                <div class="input-group clockpicker" data-autoclose="true">
                                    <input type="text" id="start-time" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label>Fecha de fin:</label>
                                <div class="input-group" data-autoclose="true">
                                    <input type="date" id="end-date" class="form-control" value="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="title-hour-end">
                                <label>Hora de fin:</label>
                                <div class="input-group clockpicker" data-autoclose="true">
                                    <input type="text" id="end-time" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label>Descripción:</label>
                            <textarea id="description-event" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label>Color de fondo:</label>
                            <input type="color" value="#3788D8" id="color-font" class="form-control" style="height: 36px;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label>Color de texto:</label>
                            <input type="color" value="#FFFFFF" id="color-text" class="form-control" style="height: 36px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" id="btn-add-event" class="btn btn-success">Agregar</button>
                        <button type="button" id="btn-modify-event" class="btn btn-success">Modificar</button>
                        <button type="button" id="btn-remove-event" class="btn btn-success">Eliminar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Es fundamental que menciones qué versión de Boostrap estás utilizando. Al parecer, utilizás la versión 5, en donde [`form-row` es eliminada](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/migration/#forms-1). La documentación misma sugiere usar en su reemplazo la grilla de BS y sus utilidades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que usar la clase `row` en vez de `form-row`, ya que la clase `form-row` [**ha sido eliminada**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#forms) a partir de la versión 5 de Bootstrap, así funcionarían tus rejillas (que son las clases `col-md-6`) que tienes dentro:

```
<div class="row"> <!-- usamos el "row" -->
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="title-hour-start">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row"> <!-- usamos el "row" -->
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="title-hour-end">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Calendario WEB</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#form-events">
      Abrir Modal
    </button>
    <!-- Formulario de Eventos -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="form-events" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header" style="background:#293145;">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="hidden" id="Id">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group col-12">
                <label>Titulo del Evento:</label>
                <input type="text" id="title-event" class="form-control" placeholder="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label>Fecha de inicio:</label>
                <div class="input-group" data-autoclose="true">
                  <input type="date" id="start-date" class="form-control" value="">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="title-hour-start">
                <label>Hora de inicio:</label>
                <div class="input-group clockpicker" data-autoclose="true">
                  <input type="text" id="start-time" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label>Fecha de fin:</label>
                <div class="input-group" data-autoclose="true">
                  <input type="date" id="end-date" class="form-control" value="">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="title-hour-end">
                <label>Hora de fin:</label>
                <div class="input-group clockpicker" data-autoclose="true">
                  <input type="text" id="end-time" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
              <label>Descripción:</label>
              <textarea id="description-event" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
              <label>Color de fondo:</label>
              <input type="color" value="#3788D8" id="color-font" class="form-control" style="height: 36px;">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
              <label>Color de texto:</label>
              <input type="color" value="#FFFFFF" id="color-text" class="form-control" style="height: 36px;">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="btn-add-event" class="btn btn-success">Agregar</button>
            <button type="button" id="btn-modify-event" class="btn btn-success">Modificar</button>
            <button type="button" id="btn-remove-event" class="btn btn-success">Eliminar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `form-row` existía hasta Bootstrap 4. Probablemente esté usando la versión 5 (por lo tanto se podría eliminar esa clase sin problema en la respuesta) (?

Answer (score 1):

La clase `form-row` no se de donde la sacaste, pero en tu código no hace nada. Debes reemplazarla por `row`, por lo menos en las filas que tengan más de una columna

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Calendario WEB</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#form-events">
            Abrir Modal
        </button>
        <!-- Formulario de Eventos -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="form-events" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header" style="background:#293145;">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <input type="hidden" id="Id">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-12">
                                <label>Titulo del Evento:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="title-event" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label>Fecha de inicio:</label>
                                <div class="input-group" data-autoclose="true">
                                    <input type="date" id="start-date" class="form-control" value="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="title-hour-start">
                                <label>Hora de inicio:</label>
                                <div class="input-group clockpicker" data-autoclose="true">
                                    <input type="text" id="start-time" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label>Fecha de fin:</label>
                                <div class="input-group" data-autoclose="true">
                                    <input type="date" id="end-date" class="form-control" value="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="title-hour-end">
                                <label>Hora de fin:</label>
                                <div class="input-group clockpicker" data-autoclose="true">
                                    <input type="text" id="end-time" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label>Descripción:</label>
                            <textarea id="description-event" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label>Color de fondo:</label>
                            <input type="color" value="#3788D8" id="color-font" class="form-control" style="height: 36px;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label>Color de texto:</label>
                            <input type="color" value="#FFFFFF" id="color-text" class="form-control" style="height: 36px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" id="btn-add-event" class="btn btn-success">Agregar</button>
                        <button type="button" id="btn-modify-event" class="btn btn-success">Modificar</button>
                        <button type="button" id="btn-remove-event" class="btn btn-success">Eliminar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `form-row` existía hasta Bootstrap 4. Probablemente esté usando la versión 5.

Comment: @padaleiana La está usando, él agrego esa versión en su [MRE]

Comment: Sí. Cosas que pasan cuando uno da un vistazo muy rápido (?

Comment: @padaleiana MUAJAJA le he ganado al ojo de águila de padaleiana :)